# Bernoulli measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Does anyone know an elementary proof (or somewhere I can find it) of the construction of Bernoulli measure on the set of infinite binary sequences? I am having trouble to show that the measure defined on cylinders' algebra is sigma additive (which then would complete the construction, by the extension theorem). 
By elementary, I mean something that relies only on basic measure theory, no advanced probability.

Comment: Your problem is actually equivalent to the construction of the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, do you see why? So I'm afraid you won't find any really elementary proof.

Comment: Well, it's not, because I am actually with different probabilities for 0 and 1.

Comment: I ve just realized that is the same as constructing the product measure :)